# Robot Framework error in counting rows from table

Tags: python, python-2.7, robotframework

I am trying to count the number of all rows in a table that can be visible on the page as 10, 20, or 50 rows table. I have 71 records in the database, so on the page, when I select 10 rows per page, There are 8 table links . The following code works fine and returns sum of the rows till 6th page where it shows that the aggregated value is 60, but in the next iteration it fails to count 10 records of 7th page and returns only 1 so I get total of 61 instead of 71. It seems to ignore a page in the process.

After Hemanthvrm's comment below, I looked into the html and discovered that this issue is due to the range issue on the page navigation table. This page navigation table has 10 boxes 
`<Prev>|1|2|3|4|5|...|8|<Next>`

The xpaths are here ranging from //*[@id="study_paginate"]/ul/li[2]/a to //*[@id="study_paginate"]/ul/li[8]/a

But when the page 5 is clicked, The navigation table changes to

`<Prev>|1|...|4|5|6|7|8|<Next>`

But the xpaths remains same for the relative positions, so previously //*[@id="study_paginate"]/ul/li[6]/a referred to page 5, and after clicking page 5, the same //*[@id="study_paginate"]/ul/li[6]/a now refers to page 6. Since the system already clicked this xpath (page 5), so after five it clicks //*[@id="study_paginate"]/ul/li[7]/a, which refers to page 7 now. so the page 6 is totally omitted.

```
SAS_Temp_Tests
[Tags]    TEMP
Open Browser    http://localhost:5000/login/    Chrome
Maximize Browser Window
Wait Until Element Is Visible    id=submit
Input Text    id=email    ${User_Email}
Input Password    password    ${User_PW}
Click Element    id=submit
sleep    2s
Click Element    ${User_Menu Link}
Wait Until Element Is Visible    ${User_menu_Study_admin_Panel Link}
Click Element    ${User_menu_Study_admin_Panel Link}
sleep    3s
Comment    Click Element    xpath=//*[@id="study_length"]/label/select/option[4]
${rows}=    Get Matching Xpath Count    //*[@id="study"]/tbody/tr
Log    ${rows}
${Row_num}=    Evaluate    0
Set Global Variable    ${Row_num}
Log    ${Row_num}
: FOR    ${x}    IN RANGE    2    9999999
\    ${page}=    Run Keyword And Return Status    Element Should Be Visible    xpath=//*[@id="study_paginate"]/ul/li[${x}]/a
     ${y}    Evaluate    ${x}+1
\    ${No_Page}    Run Keyword And Return Status    Element Should Not Be Visible    xpath=//*[@id="study_paginate"]/ul/li[${y}]/a
\    Exit For Loop If    ${No_Page}
\    Click Element    xpath=//*[@id="study_paginate"]/ul/li[${x}]/a
\    Wait Until Element Is Visible    xpath=//*[@id="study"]
\    sleep    1s
\    ${rows}=    Get Matching Xpath Count    //*[@id="study"]/tbody/tr
\    ${Row_num}    Evaluate    ${Row_num}+${rows}
\    Log    ${Row_num}
Close All Browsers
```

With this update, any suggestions how can I overcome the issue?

Answer (score -2):

Everything Looks good

*Have you tested passing only 7 in ${x}? If yes then have u got 1 or 10? 
*Have you compared table format in 7 with 6th?

Comment: Hi, I have updated the problem after I looked into the HTML code once more. Please check and let me know if you have any suggestions.